# How to compile LaTeX out-of-source while using bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, external-files, auxiliary-files, filesystem-access

I often use the out-of-source compilation on my LaTeX code to separate the generated files from the source files, thus I can conveniently commit my code to the repository. The command is like this:

```
pdflatex -c-style-errors -include-directory=dir_of_source_files -output-directory=dir_of_generated_files -aux-directory=dir_of_aux_files main_tex_file.tex
```

As the options indicated, the generated files are well managed by the compiler. Recently, I turn to `bibtex` to manage my bibliography instead of typing the `bibitem`s directly in a tex file. And I would like to use the workflow as above - to put the generated file into another directory. As a result, I failed. This is the test snippet:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
The device \cite{Vikas01} is special \cite{Bernard03}.
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

The content of the bib file is:

```
@BOOK{Bernard03,
  AUTHOR={Bernard Desgraupes},
  TITLE={{\LaTeX}, {A}pprentissage, guide et r{\'e}f{\'e}rence},
  PUBLISHER={Vuibert},
  YEAR={2003},
  address={Paris},
  edition={second},
  month={mar}}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Vikas01,
  AUTHOR={Kawadia, Vikas},
  TITLE={Protocols for Media Access Control and Power Control in Wireless Networks},
  BOOKTITLE={40th IEEE Conference on Decision and Control},
  YEAR={2001},
  month={mar}}
```

And my compilation commands are:

```
pdflatex -c-style-errors -include-directory=dir_of_source_files -output-directory=dir_of_generated_files -aux-directory=dir_of_aux_files main_tex_file.tex
bibtex -include-directory=dir_of_aux_files main_tex_file
```

Then the prompt comes out:

```
I couldn't open file name 'refs.aux'
```

And there is also a suspicious warning in the log file:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Vikas01' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Bernard03' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.

No file testbib.bbl.
[1
] (d:\tex\bin\testbib-shadow\au\testbib.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
)
```

I guess that the compiler failed to generate the .bbl file. How to fix this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) I ran your example and it worked without errors or warnings. I used pdfTeXify in WindEdt+MiKTeX. Did you run the required number of times? The warnings you get are typical from the first run where the files required for proper formatting are generated.

Comment: @PeterJansson Thanks for your help! Then you're testing the snippet in an IDE while my target is to do it in the **windows command line** and compile it *out-of-source*, or you can call it *shadow build*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bibtex` does not have a `-include-directory` switch, so it has to see the `.aux` file of your document in the directory where it is invoked.

Therefore,

```
bibtex dir_of_aux_files/main_tex_file
```

should be used, where `main_tex_file` is of course without the `.tex` at the end.

Comment: It is just a slightly modification to enable that. But what I want to add is that `bibtex` **does** have a `-include-directory` switch although it doesn't work well on my machine with Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and MikTex-BibTeX 2.8.3581 (0.99c). :)

Comment: @stoneyang Interesting. I too have version 0.99c, and I swear it has no `-include-directory` switch. But I use Linux, so maybe the MiKTeX people patched `bibtex`.